# How to add bootstrap sidebar and navbar in a line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have sample code of sidebar and navbar with Bootstrap.

I don't know how to add a sidebar same line in the navbar.

Like this:

```
sidebar     logo    navbar {item 1, item 2, item 3}
```

That mean

My pen at http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/MbYzpE

It only shows navigation bar and not show any button-like toggle button to open the sidebar.

Comment: you need to tweak the default navbar. Read on bootstrap grid layouts doc

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple bootstrap with sidebar implementation [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcjnuh0d/) .

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="custom-sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <br>
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <a href="#" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-reorder"></i></a>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>dajsdnaksjndkajsndkjas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Section</h2>
                    <p>asdkasdkmaskdmaskdmkasmdkwuidnjdnajdjkansdjkasndjkasndkajsndkajsndkajsndkjasd</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript. Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to
                        facilitate responsive Web design. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->

                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to facilitate responsive Web design. Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap
                        friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to facilitate responsive Web design. Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap
                        friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->


    </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>© Footer here</p>
    </footer>

</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    background:#ecf0f1;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -40%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 40%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 12px;
  }
}

#custom-sidebar {
    padding:15px;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: -56px;
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: In the left panel, I want to add an icon to collapse menu. When click it can open or close this panel.

Comment: So you mean the sidebar on the top will be an togglable icon?

Comment: Yes, like this. http://mdbootstrap.com/live/_MDB/index/docs/skins/skin-blue.html . When I click `fa-bars` it will slide out a sidebar. Normal, it shows only icon `fa-bars`.